# HTML and JSP binding commands to option form

Tags: java, html, jsp, html-select

I am having a little problem trying to bind an action to an HTML select option.
At the moment I have:

```
<select name ="delivery ">
    <p><option value="1"</p>Free Delivery</option>                            
    <p><option value="2"</p>Next-day</option>                        
</select>
```

If option one is pressed, then I would like `${cart.subtotal}` to remain the same value
but if option 2 is pressed then `${cart.subtotal + 3.50}`

Comment: First your html code is illegal,and then I don't know what's the ${cart.subtotal} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change entries like `<p><option value="1"</p>Free Delivery</option>` to

`<option value="1">Free Delivery</option>`

Secondly if you use jQuery to bind action then the jQuery code should be:

```
$("select[name='delivery']").change(function() {
//do something here
});
```

Also remove unnecessary space

from `<select name ="delivery ">`

change it to `<select name ="delivery">`